# How come VBA excel keeps running the statement inside a conditional statement even if it is false?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an automatic filling of the payroll spreadsheet I created. However, no matter how much I try it the value of z = 1 all the time even if the logic returns FALSE values (I validated this using MsgBox).

My goal in this code is to check whether there is already a record in another sheet. If there isn't it will automatically add the record with the appropriate details based on the available data.

Below is the full VBA code (Note code is incomplete so it is a bit unpolished still):

```
Option Explicit

Public p As Long

Sub test()

    Dim Total_rows_PR As Long
    Dim Total_rows_DTR As Long

    Total_rows_PR = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Total_rows_DTR = Worksheets("DTR").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim q As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim z As Long

    For j = 1 To Total_rows_DTR - 1
        For q = 1 To Total_rows_PR + p - 2
            If Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 33) = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(2 + q, 1) Then
                If Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 34) = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(2 + q, 2) Then
                    If Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 2) = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(2 + q, 3) Then
                        z = 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next q

' Below is where the assignment should happen but only returns a blank cell

        If z = 0 Then Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(Total_rows_PR + 1 + p, 1) = Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 33)
        If z = 0 Then Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(Total_rows_PR + 1 + p, 2) = Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 34)
        If z = 0 Then Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(Total_rows_PR + 1 + p, 3) = Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 2)
        If z = 0 Then p = p + 1
        z = 0
    Next j

End Sub
```

Update: I realized that even if the conditions are not being a met in the first portion of If-Then loops, the value of z is set to 1 for no reason. This is the reason why it won't assign values. However, I do not see why it keeps assigning  to 1.

Update#2: @ShaiRado
[image: DTR Table]

So the first image is where data is encoded (not shown in image because it is in the leftmost part of the spreadsheet, but basically it inputs the name of the person, date, and the daily time record (DTR) of the person). When the data is encoded, it will automatically indicate what month and year it is based on the helper column AG month and column AH for year. Somewhere in the start of the same worksheet at column B is where the name of the person is. All of these 3 will be used.

[image: Payroll - Regular Table]

This second image is where the summaries are computed. If there is an entry for a specific person at a certain month and year and it is not located in this worksheet, it will automatically fill in that person's name as well as the month and year. Basically that's what the code i'm trying to create does.

The output is a fully automated spreadsheet that only requires data entry in the DTR sheet. All computations already have their corresponding formulas.

Comment: at which line is it not assigning the value ? can you tell us more ?

Comment: Sorry i'm trying to format it properly. I edited it already

Comment: you have some syntax missing at : `If Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 33) = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(2 + q, 1) _
            Then If Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 34) = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(2 + q, 2) _
            Then If Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 2) = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(2 + q, 3) _
            Then z = 1` , you need to close every `If` with `End If`

Comment: Oh that explains it. I am confused because when I was reading the VBA book I was reading some If-Then conditions had an End If while some others did not have End If. It is quite confusing. Is there a general rule?

Comment: When I do add End If after z = 1 on the same line, it has an error saying: "Compile error: Expected: end of statement", but if I put the End If in the line below z = 1, it has an error: "Compile error: End If without block If"

Comment: When I move the statements to the next line after the "Then" End If will work without error, but as it is, it won't let me add End If... VBA is hella confusing!! It is unlike any other programming language I used. But same problem, it keeps assigning z = 1 for no reason

Comment: @marc writing your If as a single line is probably obscuring a logic error.  Try breaking it into seperate lines (with end if's) and checking the logic

Comment: @ShaiRado a single line If Then like this does not require an End If (note the line continuations). That said, writing this as a single line is a really bad idea

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for that. I already fixed it with End Ifs into separate lines. However, still can't get the code to work. z = 1 despite not being equal. Still trying to figure it out

Comment: @MarcSantos can you eaxplain better what you are trying to achieve ? maybe share a screen-shot of your data, and your desired result

Comment: @YowE3K why not just use one `If` with `And` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado A comment by the OP in the answer by FunThomas makes me remember why sometimes the OP's style could be better - the "inner" `If` statements are only evaluated if the previous ones are `True`, while using `And` requires all parts to be evaluated.  So if an inner logical expression would error if the outer one was `False`, the OP's code will avoid the error.  The OP's style is equivalent to a VB.Net `AndAlso` operator.  (E.g. `If x > 0 Then If y / x = 2 Then z = 1` is safe while `If x > 0 And y / x = 2 Then z = 1` would error if `x` was 0.)

Comment: @ShaiRado I have made edits in the post. Updated the code to the latest version.

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- please read and apply.

Comment: Will do thank you @Andre

Comment: Already found the problem thanks to the debugging tips. It was due to automatically generated rows from previous tests that was placed around row 700. Didn't see this and it caused the code to malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

First: You have a really strange way of writing your if-statements.
I think what you mean is

```
For q = 1 To Total_rows_PR + p
    If Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 33) = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(2 + q, 1) _
       And Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 34) = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(2 + q, 2) _
       And Worksheets("DTR").Cells(1 + j, 2) = Worksheets("Payroll - Regular").Cells(2 + q, 3) Then
        z = 1
        Exit For ' Once found, z stays 1 so you don't have to continue the inner loop.
    End If
Next q
```

Second: I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but as far as I understand, your problem is that you are looping to far. At the last iteration of the outer loop, your accessing row `1 + j` of sheet DTR which is empty at that time, and you are accessing row `2 + q` (which is the same as `2 + Total_rows_PR + p`) - also empty (and comparing the two emtpy lines sets z to 1).

> A variable is never set *for no reason.* Is is maybe set and you don't understand the reason.

Debug your code step by step, watch where it behaves different as you expect and find the reason why it does what is does.

Comment: I wrote many Ifs because when I tried to put "and" for conjunction it errors. Perhaps its the way the lines are arranged which makes it quite unique to VBA unlike other languages. Just realized it with the "End If" statements

Comment: @YowE3K: Yes, you're right. For once I didn't test it in the VBA Editor but did the editing in Notepad++ - learned my lesson. Will correct my answer

Comment: You're right I made a mistake on defining the loop boundaries. I changed the "ifs" to "and", and I get the error: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch". This is the reason why I looped it in a weird manner of making many If-Thens.

Comment: I already made the adjustments to the loop boundaries. I reverted the `and` back to `if-then` because I can't seem to get it to work. But I added the `Exit For`. But code still won't work